# Why does Ruby include multiple print functions?

Tags: ruby

While working through the Ruby Codecademy exercises, I came across puts() and print().  The difference is that one adds a newline and the other doesn't.  Is this a considered design decision, or just evolving code?  It seems strange to me to have two (quite differently-named) functions for this. Why not an additional argument, or some other solution?

Edit: To clarify, I'm most interested in why these particular names were chosen, since they don't seem to relate to the difference in functionality.

Comment: Personally, I'm quite happy not to have to append linebreaks or additional arguments when I can just `puts "a line"`

Comment: `print :new_line => true, "Here sometext"` vs `puts "Here sometext"`- nahhhh

Comment: What about print vs. println?  Why the two different verbs and concepts?

Answer (score 3):

I always thought it came from C, where you have `puts` which prints strings with a new line and `printf` which prints strings with interpolated values by type (but no new line).

Similarly in Ruby you have `puts` which does the same thing, and `print` with #{} for interpolation. The difference with C is obviously that interpolation is built right into strings, and can be used in either, or outside a print statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just for convenience, as printing a line with newline is a rather common task in day to day development.

In the Perl language for example they explicitly introduced a say() function (equivalent to ruby's  puts) 1997 with Perl 5.10 while Perl is around for a long, long time. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm hoping that someone with knowledge of Ruby design decisions can chime in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because Ruby is unix oriented, and it inherits some oddities carried from it. Particularly, since the terminal is line oriented, i.e., user inputs a line, then the program responds with lines, user inputs a line, ..., it is so frequent that you want to end the line whenever you print out something, hence there is `puts`. However, there are (not so frequent) cases where you do not want to end a line, and that is why there is `print`.

Although I do not feel unnatural to have both `print` and `puts`, I do feel unnatural that `puts` is considered more basic than `print`, and in introductory document of Ruby, there is almost always `puts` introduced at the beginning, but `print` is barely explained. Since `print` is a more elementary operation, and `puts` is built on top of it, and is slower, textbooks should introduce `print` first, then go on to say that `puts` is a shorthand for `print "...#$/"`.

Comment: I meant to ask more about naming and intuition.  I understand the argument from history, but why these two particular names, instead of say, "print" and "println"?

Comment: Simplex words are easier to recognize for human. Complex words require more human brain power. Association between words and concepts are more direct with simplex words than with complex words. Imagine you were halfway asleep or drunk. Is it easier to tell the difference between "print" and "println", or "print" and "puts"?

Comment: "puts" is short for "put string", but since it is recognized as a single concept, and is entirely different from "print", that helps.

Comment: How is puts an entirely different concept than print?

Comment: @DustinRasener Didn't you acknowledge that? I thought you were saying that these words look different.

Comment: They look different, but they are the same concept. (show a string in the console)